# Creating an enterprise maven application using spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, maven-3

We have a specific requirement that only Enterprise Archive (EAR) should be deployed on our application server (Web Logic).

1. Can spring-boot be used for such type of Enterprise applications?
2. As spring-boot provide an inbuilt Jetty/Tomcat server, can I use the jar/war     to be deployed on Web Logic application server?
3. Also we have some external dependencies (not from maven central)
   which have to be included in the pom. Does that impact spring-boot
   configurations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Of course it can - as Spring itself. You can read about it  here http://www.virtual7.de/blog/2016/07/spring-boot-oracle-weblogic-server-12/
2. Yes, here is the instruction how to do it: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html
3. It depends what are those dependencies. There could be some conflicts, but any conflict can be resolved somehow :)

Comment: Please avoid link only answers, You can summarize.

Comment: Please refer : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers